# Error with openFileOutput in Fragments

Tags: android, local-storage, fragment

I'm reading the [API Guides - Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and I'm going crazy with an error. I'm trying to implement `openFileOutput` in a fragment but I can't do it.

Android Studio gives me the following error in `FileOutputStream fos = fileContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, fileContext.MODE_PRIVATE);` line.

> Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Here is the full code:

```
public class SavingDataFragment extends Fragment {

EditText entryData;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragent_saving_data, container, false);
}

public void saveInInternalStorage (View view, Context fileContext){

    entryData = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtText_entry_SavingData);
    String dataToSave = entryData.getText().toString();

    String FILENAME = "myFile";

    FileOutputStream fos = fileContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, fileContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

A lot of thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that you have to catch the `FileNotFoundException` that `openFileOutput()` can potentially throw :

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = fileContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, fileContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // Handle the error here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
FileOutputStream stream = getActivity().openFileOutput("lang.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```